# Regarding the definition of operation in google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm thinking of adding a csv file from Google cloud storage to Google data portal as a data source.
Now I'm going to use the data portal feature to filter the data in the csv file using some ID and add some of the csv data to the data source.

- Which operation does this operation belong to, Class A or B?
- When adding data after filtering, is the data capacity after filtering counted as a network usage fee?

We are considering whether cloud storage can be used for free.

Answer (score 0):

On Cloud Storage, when you get an object (metadata or data) it's a [class B operation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing)

Everytime that you access the file, you perform that access (but it's very, very cheap).

The egress is absolutely not clear at this stage for 2 reasons:

- The egress is billable is you go outside of Google Cloud datacenter. If you stay in the same region, there is no egress fee.
- Data Studio (and data portal) are now part of Google Cloud (since a few month ago)

Because you don't know if egress cost apply on DataStudio and you don't know in which region run Datastudio (compare to your GCS bucket location), it's impossible to say today the cost of that architecture (and even at Google Cloud, I'm not sure that many are able to provide you that answer!!)

And, you also don't know at which frequency DataStudio access the file to apply filter (request every time or keep cache locally). It's also hard/impossible to tell you the number of API call.

---

That being said, even if it cost you something, it will be very very very low (more than $1/month should be exceptional!)